# MySQL - Disabling the innodb_log_file

Tags: mysql, innodb

Innodb by default writes a log file named ib_logfile0, ib_logefile1 etc..

I can see that this writes are taking a lot of disk resources at my server, My question is, are this logfiles a must? or can i disable them by anyhow? or maybe I shouldn't?

Comment: They are vital; they cannot be disabled.  If you are having performance problems, let's focus on slow queries.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Oracle documentation, by default, InnoDB creates two redo log files (or just log files) `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` within the data directory of MySQL.
In MySQL versions 5.6.8 and above, the default size of each redo log file is 48MB each. This can be configured by the user by making use of `innodb_log_file_size` server option.

The generated redo log record will contain information necessary to repeat the same operation later during a database recovery. So the redo log record will contain information about the original set of pages and what has been changed in them. Using the redo log record the set of dirty pages will be re-created during database recovery.

So, as shortly I am explaining, to maintain the log sequence number(LSN) in Innodb, it is important.

For your Ref [Redo Logging in InnoDB](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/redo_logging_in_innodb)